# Как получить данные в php из post запроса

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

отправляю запрос к php этим кодом:

```
i.open("POST", t, !0), i.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"), i.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            var t = i.readyState,
                                e = i.status;
                            if (t === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
                                switch (e) {
                                case 200:
                                    s && s(i.responseText);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    n && n(i.responseText)
                                }
                        }, i.send(O()(e))
```

В переменной e изначально находятся значения формы:

```
{ 
email: "12123@ds.sd",
firstName: "13123",
flag: null,
lastName: "3213123",
message: "131231",
phone: "1231231"
}
```

в виде объекта.

в переменной t url до файла /script/contact-slack.php

в файле php пытаюсь получить данные формы, но распечатав переменную $_POST  получаю пустой массив. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

получилось получить данные из форм через:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```